# How to handle responsive layout in React Native

Tags: react-native, responsive-design

I'm using the `react-native-dimension` library for making my UI responsive as follows:

```
const{width,height} = Dimensions.get('window');
```

and in my style.js file :

```
imageBackgroundLandscape:{
    width:height,
    height:width

},
imageBackgroundPortrait:{
    width:width,
    height:height
}
```

The problem is that when I rotate the screen, the width and height variables have got previous values! 
For example in the portrait mode my variables are:

```
width : 800
height: 1280
```

and when I rotate the screen my variables are:

```
width : 800 // previous value
height: 1280 // previous value
```

In addition, I use the react-native-orientation to determine the mode of the screen.
I want to know how can I change the values of them (width, height) automatically when I rotate the device, or are there any other libraries for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i recomend this lib : https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually handle the `height, width` confusion with the following code:

```
//Dimensions.js
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');

const actualDimensions =  {
  height:  (height<width) ? width : height,
  width: (width>height) ? height : width
};

export default actualDimensions;
```

Instead of requiring the height and width from Dimensions, use the `actualDimensions` and for managing the orientation gracefully you should give a try to [this](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) library as well.

The `Dimensions` are loaded before the JS bundle gets loaded into the app so it is recommended to fetch the `height, width` dynamically for every `render` 
You can read this [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions#get)

Answer (score 4):

I usually used Flexbox to arrange the layout for my components. It helps them to be responsive. Maybe you could give a try too.

[Layout with Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox)

Answer (score 3):

**You can use these steps to make your UI responsive.**

```
  1: use percentage whenever it's possible
  2: use the power of flexbox to make your UI grow and shrink
  3: use Dimension API
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do right but half of the task. you got the `width` and `height` from `Dimensions` and it is right, but how `react-native` understand your orientation changes?

First, your code should understand the change of orientation, then you set a call-back function to change the state of your application for implementing new `width` and `height`.

Awfully, I don't know the `react-native` can understand a change of orientation with its built-in functions or not. So I'm using [this library](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation#readme) to understand orientation changes and then I use `setState` to re-render the codes.

Absolutely, I put the `width` and `height` inside `state` of the component.

If you wanna lock the orientation change, use [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker).

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**:

You are facing that issue is because you forgot to call `const{width,height} 
= Dimensions.get('window');` again when the orientation has changed.
In order to get the latest value of `width` and `height` after the orientation change you would have to call the `Dimensions.get('window')` function again and get width and height from it's output.

**Secondly**:

Instead of using multiple libraries, you can just use one library([react-native-styleman](https://github.com/anubhavgupta/react-native-styleman)), that lets you handle this type of stuff very easily:

Here is how the code would look like using [react-native-styleman](https://github.com/anubhavgupta/react-native-styleman).

```js
import { withStyles } from 'react-native-styleman';
const styles = () => ({       
    container: {
        // your common styles here for container node.
        flex: 1,
        // lets write a media query to change background color automatically based on the device's orientation 
        '@media': [
          {
             orientation: 'landscape', // for landscape
             styles: {                 // apply following styles
                // these styles would be applied when the device is in landscape 
                // mode.
                 backgroundColor: 'green'
                 //.... more landscape related styles here...
             }
          },
          {
             orientation: 'portrait', // for portrait
             styles: {                // apply folllowing styles
                // these styles would be applied when the device is in portrait 
                // mode.
                 backgroundColor: 'red'
                 //.... more protrait related styles here...
             }
          }
        ]
    }
});

let MainComponent = ({ styles })=>(
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> Hello World </Text>
    </View>
);

// now, lets wire up things together.
MainComponent = withStyles(styles)(MainComponent);

export {
  MainComponent
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using [react-native-responsive-screen](https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen/tree/master/examples/responsive-screen-orientation-change). it is working also with orientation change

USAGE

```
import {
  widthPercentageToDP as wp,
  heightPercentageToDP as hp,
  listenOrientationChange as lor,
  removeOrientationListener as rol
} from 'react-native-responsive-screen';

class Login extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    lor(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    rol();
  }

  render() {
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: { flex: 1 },
      textWrapper: {
        height: hp('70%'),
        width: wp('80%')
      },
      myText: { fontSize: hp('5%') }
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.textWrapper}>
          <Text style={styles.myText}>Login</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```